# Mercurial get branch name by changeset

Tags: mercurial, hg-log

I have tried the

```
hg log --rev "branch([changeset])"
```

but what I got is a collection of all the changesets in this branch.

What I do want to get is the name of the target branch (e.g. default) instead of the whole collection.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's... not what revsets are for.  You want to do something rather different:

```
hg log --rev [changeset] --template "{branch}\n"
```

See [`hg help templates`](https://selenic.com/hg/help/templates).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get the branch name from the result of `hg log --rev`, which does not show the branch name by default. It appears that under the hood the branch name is in scope and can be used in a template. Cool!