# How do I get the Branch Name from hg log?

Tags: mercurial

Basically, I want to get all my open branches, like this:

```
hg log --rev "author('ME') and head() and not closed()"
```

and show the branch name in the result when I run this command in the terminal.

Comment: This question is technically a dupe, however (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881351/mercurial-get-branch-name-by-changeset) is, unfortunately, neither Google nor Stackoverflow search friendly for this  problem situation. So this question is an additional discovery vector for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I found out templates can handle this.

```
hg log --rev "author('ME') and head() and not closed()" --template {branch\n}
```